# Rancher won't install new version of a catalog

Tags: rancher

I have an existing catalog (v0.1.0)installed. I also have a new 1.1.0 and I want to upgrade my App to this.
 But when I upgrade it to 1.1.0 it still installs the 0.1.0 however it says that it was successfull and up-to-date with 1.1.0.

here is my index.yaml from the repository:

```
  mychart:
  - appVersion: 1.0.0
    created: 2020-08-01T06:56:55.796Z
    description: descr
    digest: a62...
    name: mychart
    urls:
    - mychart-0.1.0.tgz
    version: 0.1.0
  - appVersion: 1.1.0
    created: 2020-09-23T09:24:48.892Z
    description: descr
    digest: 563...
    name: mychart
    urls:
    - mychart-1.1.0.tgz
    version: 1.1.0
```

So now Rancher UI says I have a catalog of 1.1.0 installed which is not true.

At the catalog upgrade page I select 1.1.0 and in the preview section it shows files from the 0.1.0.
When I refresh(!!) the page it shows the correct new files from 1.1.0, however the upgrade itself still installs the 0.1.0 one.

What is wrong with it?

edit: Also tried to delete catalog/clear cache/readd the catalog. Still the same issue